# Use page properties to filter content on modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, highlighted-content-web-part

I have a SPO site with modern pages. I've given the pages some extra metadata and am using the [Page Properties webpart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-page-properties-web-part-1a99cb9c-a5f1-441b-8e5d-643b0f0ff736?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=wssenduser_pagepropertieswebpart_fl871982&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

I'm trying to use the [Highlighted content webpart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) to show content specifically related to the current page.

For example, if the current page is about our Oregon service region I want to show documents from a library (on the same site) which have Oregon as a keyword.

I can do this if I open the highlighted content webpart settings and manually enter Oregon in the filter and sort settings, but I have a lot of pages to do and that is likely to result in typos and mistakes.

I'm trying to find a way to access the page properties and have that dynamically inserted into the filter.

I don't have to use the highlighted content webpart. I also tried the [PnP Modern Search webpart](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/). There is a setting in one of the configuration panels for the web part that lets you create a dynamic search query connected to the "Page environment, but I can't figure out how to use that. There is no option to actually select data associated with the page, so I'm thinking "page environment" means something else.

[image: Enhanced search web part configuration panel]

Is there a way to dynamically filter content on a page so that it relates to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [PnP Search](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/). You can use [Page Token](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/#page-tokens) where you can configure query according to current page property values.

You can configure search query as below:

```
{YourManagedPropertyName}:{Page.[InternalNameOfField]}
```

E.g. Let say you have managed metadata column with internal name `TESTDepartment` and you have added same column in Site Pages and Document Library then your query should look like shown in below screen shot: (In my case I do have managed metadata column hence I am using `{Page.TESTDepartment.TermID}` but in your case if you do have normal text or choice column then you can use it like `{Page.TESTDepartment}` without `TermID`)

[image]

Document Library Content:

[image]

Site Pages Library:

[image]

You need to create managed property for your field which you want to filter. You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#create-a-new-managed-property) link to do so. In my case managed property look like as below:

[image]

After creating managed property, if you don't get result immediately then please wait for some time for crawl.